# How can I retrieve last x elements in Django

Tags: python, django, list

I am trying to retrieve the latest 5 posts (by post time)
In the views.py, if I try `blog_post_list = blogPosts.objects.all()[:5]` It retreives the first 5 elements of the blogPosts objects, how can I reverse this to retreive the latest ones?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Nick Presta's answer and your comment, try:

```
blog_post_list = blogPosts.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

Answer (score 8):

```
blog_post_list = blogPosts.objects.all().reverse()[:5]
# OR
blog_post_list = blogPosts.objects.all().order_by('-DEFAULT_ORDER_KEY')[:5]
```

I prefer the first.

Comment: the first one doesn't seem to work for me.
And for the second one I get this error:
" Caught an exception while rendering: Cannot resolve keyword 'DEFAULT_ORDER_KEY' into field. Choices are: id, postInput, pub_date "

Comment: DEFAULT_ORDER_KEY is your order key. You can sort by id, etc. For a blog application, you may want to order by last posted date, in which case the code would be: blogPosts.objects.all().order_by('last_posted')